# SQL server function sum and average counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum

I have two fields with numbers and average but when i trying get total amount first row always NULL.

```
INSERT INTO weight(
DATE,
WEIGHT1,
WEIGHT2,
AVERAGE_WEIGHT,
TOTAL
)
VALUES (
GetDate(),
convert(real, '518'),
convert(real, '510'),

convert(real, '514'),
(SELECT SUM(average_weight) FROM weight)
)
```

This query work but problem is somewere with sum function.

```
WEIGHT1 WEIGHT2 AWERAGE_WEIGHT TOTAL
518      510     514            0
518      510     514           514
```

First row (TOTAL) should be 514 Sec row (TOTAL) should be 1028
How to get right values in right plase?

Comment: i think column name is AWERAGE_WEIGHT

Comment: yes. i say query work fine. But how to get right values?

Comment: Can you do something like (convert(real, '514')+SELECT SUM(average_weight)) add the previous total sum + the new average.

Comment: Please don't use tags that aren't related to the question.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE its good but by first TOTAL still NULL but sec right

Comment: Try (select COALESCE(sum(average_weight),0) FROM weight+(convert(real, '514')) the COALESCE should return 0 when null for first insert

Comment: Will be allright thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your select is getting the current total before your new value has been inserted - try this:

```
INSERT INTO weight(
DATE,
WEIGHT1,
WEIGHT2,
AVERAGE_WEIGHT,
TOTAL
)
VALUES (
GetDate(),
convert(real, '518'),
convert(real, '510'),

convert(real, '514'),
(SELECT SUM(average_weight) + convert(real, '514')  FROM weight)
```

)